# HTTP transfert encoding chunked decode PHP

Tags: php, http, decode

I have this HTTP response content :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 12 Aug 2013 15:08:10 GMT
PK�Ctemps_attente.json���n� �߅9�Bw���VU��Uߠs���^��#�CGç��ͷ�r7G�3Hnp����^pYSu\@Qo%~x��FGa�Y�ا����S���-ua���t��j-���s�%э��+,g�xq.��������t�fb� �0:)�:�K�}^�N�L����>�֌щ%#�̲x`C@��m݃ :^��$~�i8���WzCh�a�ă���7t�O|��AX˂��UO$���<��y"�;�'F��]��{֘Ha}F��<��l6��o벰V���66t�&��f�Ť��x�H��툗���/PKA�Y�1�PK�CA�Y�1�temps_attente.jsonPK@q
```

I would like to know what format is the response and how to decompile to have the final response.

I tried to use this function: http_chunked_decode but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body (or at least what appears to be the body) of the response is not chunked.

It does appear to be compressed - with HTTP this should be expressly stated in the headers,

There is no blank line between the what appears to be the headers and what appears to be the body.

If this is really the response you are getting it's not HTTP - an off-the-shelf function is not going to make sense of it.

Comment: The response is actually completely broken, because it's also missing the double line-break after the headers. Don't forget that many applications that output a HTTP response take care of de-chunking, so at the point OP is grabbing the output, the de-chunking may already be complete. As a side-note, if the first 2 bytes are PK, it's likely to be zipped.